# Make JS function output while function running

Tags: javascript, function

**Javascript code**

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 1000000;
var money = 0
var i = 0
let dollars = document.getElementById("total")
let dollarclick = document.getElementById("click1")
let autoclick = document.getElementById("buyauto")

dollarclick.addEventListener("click", clicked)
autoclick.addEventListener("click", auto)
function clicked() {
  money = money + 1
  dollars.innerHTML = "$"+ money.toString()
}
function auto() {
  autoclick.disabled = true
  console.log("function skull")
  while (i<10) {
    money = money + 1
    dollars.innerHTML = "$"+ money.toString()
    sleep(1000)
    console.log(money)
    i++
  }
}
```

How to make the function output while it is running, and not let it output after the function is already finished? Keep in mind I am making a cookie clicker type game, with the auto being able to be purchased only once. Can you help me resolve this problem? The game should be able to give the points every second, and not after the function has finished. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: don't block in javascript.

Comment: You shouldn’t use a while loop to introduce a delay. The while loop will execute repeatedly as fast as it can and block anything else from happening. Consider [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in an asynchronous manner.
I have used a function (`setTimeoutAsync` [from #3 here](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/es13-javascript-features/)) that resolves a promise after a timeout, and an asynchronous recursive function (`nClicks(n)`) that uses `await` for the timeout before performing the action and awaits recursion `n` times before returning.
Then, the asynchronous event handler just needs to disable the button and wait for `nClicks(10)` to complete before doing other stuff like re-enabling the button. If you don't need to do other stuff afterwards you can omit the `async` declaration on the handler and just call `nClicks(10)` without `await`.

```js
const setTimeoutAsync = function(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, timeout)
  })
}

let money = 0
const dollars = document.getElementById('total')
const tick = () => {
  dollars.innerHTML = `$${++money}`
  console.log('tick', dollars.innerHTML)
}

const nClicks = async(n) => {
  if (n) {
    // wait one second
    await setTimeoutAsync(1000)
    // then incriment
    tick()
    // wait for recursion to complete
    await nClicks(--n)
  }
}

const dollarclick = document.getElementById('click1')
const autoclick = document.getElementById('buyauto')

dollarclick.addEventListener('click', tick)

autoclick.addEventListener('click', async() => {
  autoclick.disabled = true
  // wait for 10 cycles
  await nClicks(10)
  autoclick.disabled = false
})

const autoclickOnce = document.getElementById('buyautoOnce')
autoclickOnce.addEventListener('click', () => {
  autoclickOnce.disabled = true
  nClicks(10)
})
```

```html
<h1 id="total">$0</h1>
<button id="click1">+1</button>
<button id="buyauto">Auto</button>
<button id="buyautoOnce">Auto Once</button>
```